# How to get data from paginated REST API using WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a paginated response from an URL for example https://swapi.dev/api/people .

This endpoint gives only 9 persons per page. I want to collect all Star Wars characters using WebClient in Spring Boot app but i don't know how to crawl over pages using WebClient and retrieve all persons at one time in non blocking way. Does anyone know how to do this ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you own the API that returns the paginated response or is it owned by someone else?

Comment: I can't modify API that returns paginated response. I can only consume it's endpoint that gives paginated response similar to this one given as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the pagination was implemented by the owners of the API. It might not be possible to get all results at once, but to be sure you would need to get in touch with the ones responsible for the API.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation https://swapi.dev/documentation#people https://swapi.dev/api/people request gives all people and https://swapi.dev/api/people/1 gives first people resource. So according to documentation, there is no pagination

Comment: https://swapi.dev/api/people/1 is a different endpoint changing PathVariable {id} returns single characters data. https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2 endpoint gives list of all characters however paginated. I don't want to iterate over https://swapi.dev/api/people/1 changing ids. I wonder is there more elegant non blocking method ? I think endpoint that gives paginated list of all data is a proper one for this task.

Comment: See https://swapi.dev/about it written on Django framework. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagination-schemas . Obviosly page size not implemented in this api